# Why C++ can't be made as Python in terms of convenience

Tags: c++, python

This question may seem to be naive.
But I think it'll be much worse if I don't ask it at all.

When a discussion begins about the features of Python that the developers love the most, they usually mention list comprehension, syntax relying on indentation (thus avoiding brackets, etc.) and some other.

At such moments I ask myself a question why there can't be made a language based on C++ but having a syntax like in Python and having all the features like list comprehensions, generators.

I understand that such a language won't have all the features that Python has, e.g. `eval` or `exac` statements (because they rely on Python being an interpreting language), may be some others that I don't know of.

But I also know that there is a project called Shedskin which makes a C code of a Python code (with some restrictions on what can be used in Python code).

So, are there some real reasons why it's impossible to create such a language that will combine all the best features of Python and a very fast code that produces C++? Or it's just the turn of events that Python for some reasons became very popular and it turned out to be interpreted, so a lot of people use it for its greatest features still discontent at the speed of the code, and some of them struggle to create something (like Shedskin or Psyco) to speed it up?

Comment: all a matter of taste "syntax relying on indentation" is something I dislike with Python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291370/which-language-to-learn-c-or-python

Comment: I think Go (http://golang.org/) might be the closest to what you described.

Comment: Don't know why this was closed, but I suggest looking into writing C/C++ modules for python: http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html .

Comment: @Mozza314 For me it's not clear now, so I asked this question. There may be some interpreting features of Python that really matter. Maybe for some people the answer may be very obvious, indeed! (so they closed) :)

Comment: Nothing prevents it. You could even create a language that accepts several syntaxes. For a compiler writer, what matters is the AST. Whether the textual representation uses braces or indentation, whether the keywords are in English or Japanese, these are mostly inconsequential (though might affect the speed at which the language is parsed). The most striking difference between Python and C++ are static typing vs dynamic typing and the handling of scopes. Those features prevent Python from being translated directly. Why don't you create such a language :) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. So, it's only the matter of needing some effort to create such language? Do I understand it right, that there are no underlying  serious reasons why it can't be done? (for me it's really not a problem to explicitly state the type of the variable).

Comment: @ovgolovin: creating a language is easy (why do you think so many exist ?), creating a good language is hard and getting it adopted even harder. But no, there is no special reason why we could not create a C++ "new" syntax that could just map to the old one. However, would it be useful ? No one is going to rewrite their code from scratch just to get a new syntax. It's too costly. Furthermore, it won't solve the memory unsafe access issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google as created a language called [Golang](http://golang.org/) ( or Go).  It is a compiled language with python like syntaxe.  There are alot of video and documenttation that will answer your question there.

Comment: It is not `GoLang`. It is only `Go`. Combine it with `D`, it becomes `GoD` language. :P

Comment: Then why is Python so popular in comparison with Go?

Comment: Go is a extremly new language.  As far as I know, there is not a good debugger or ide for Go.

It is still a work in progress but maybe it will become the next hot thing.

Comment: Go and Python would appear to have a very different syntax.